# Do I need to create a new provisioning profile for iOS development if my xcode project already says 'Xcode Managed Profile'?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, provisioning-profile

I am following [this guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#3-generating-a-provisioning-profile) for setting up Firebase Cloud Messaging for iOS via Apple Push Notifications.

In this guide it specifically indicates to manually create a provisioning profile. But when I go into xcode > Signing + Capabilities, under provisioning profile, it says "Xcode managed profile". I assume this means my provisioning profile is already set automatically.

Is there any reasonn I should generate a new provisioning profile specifically when using Firebase Cloud Messaging? Why would this FCM setup guide specifically mention to create a new provisioning profile?

The reason I am confused is because my notifications are not arriving, and this is the only step of the setup process I did not use.